# Form field will not validate with onSubmit

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, onsubmit

I am trying to get a script that validates a form field to work in Chrome, IE and Firefox. The script works fine in Safari.

The problem is when I click "submit", the form does not return false with a statement stating one of the form fields is required. This happens in every browser except Safari.

Here is a link to the page that I would like help on:

www.3elementsreview.com/submit

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">

var invalid = 0;

function validation() {
 
 invalid = 0;
 
  //First Name
  if(document.getElementById("first").value == "") {
   document.getElementById("invalid-1").innerHTML = "**Your first name is required**";
   invalid += 1;
  }
  else {
   document.getElementById("invalid-1").innerHTML = "";
  }
  
  //Last Name
   
  if (document.getElementById("last").value == "") {
   document.getElementById("invalid-2").innerHTML = "**Your last name is required**";
   invalid += 1;
  }
  else {
  document.getElementById("invalid-2").innerHTML = "";
  }

Answer (score 0):

Can you post a bit of your JS code so we know what you're dealing with?  The two most likely problems are that you have a syntax error in your validation function or you didn't assign an id to one of the form inputs you are trying to reference in the function.

EDIT: Next time post your code in the actual question, but on first glance it looks like you're using == instead of === to check conditions.  Also you need to say document.myForm.myAttribute.value if you want to check the values of each attribute.

Comment: //E-Mail Address
   
  if (document.getElementById("email").value.indexOf("@",".") == -1) {
   document.getElementById("invalid-3").innerHTML = "**Please enter a valid e-mail address**";
   invalid += 1;
  }
  else {
  document.getElementById("invalid-3").innerHTML = "";
  }
  
  //Comments
   
  if (document.getElementById("message").value == "") {
   document.getElementById("invalid-4").innerHTML = "What would you like to say?";
   invalid += 1;
  }
  else {
  document.getElementById("invalid-4").innerHTML = "";
  }

Comment: if (invalid != 0) {
    return false;
   }
   else {
    return true;
   }
  }
</script>